# How to include a paper presented by someone else on CV

Tags: publications, journals, conference, cv, paper-submission

As part of a project (I work for a research org, not at a university) we submitted a paper (technically we actually submitted a panel, with our paper being one of the papers in the panel) to one of the big policy/social science conferences.

It was accepted and someone else on our team presented at the conference. I'm listed as the second author on both the actual presentation itself as well as the paper. There is no conference proceedings or anything for this conference, so it wasn't peer reviewed and isn't publicly available anywhere. But I'm an early career researcher and still hope to include it on my CV somewhere, because it is a major project and was at a prestigious conference.

One other factor may be that this project is unique in that it does not actually have a guaranteed report coming at the end (long story short, we're building a database of sorts). So there may be a future paper submitted to a peer-reviewed journal, but potentially not. What's the best way to list the conference stuff? Or should I really, really not include it?

Comment: "There is no conference proceedings or anything for this conference" Not even a list of abstracts?

Comment: There is a list of abstracts online I believe, yes.

Comment: Everybody scrapes the barrel in the beginning, and everybody knows, no shame in that. Just make sure it's clear in your CV who gave the actual talk.For example you can split the list into first author papers, other papers, first author conference contributions, other conference contributions.

Comment: So you would only do the presentation, not the paper?

Answer (score 1):

In your CV, you could write your name in bold in the author list of the paper and also make it available in a preprint repository. That way the paper will get a doi and will be freely accessible.

Comment: Making it available in a preprint repository is an excellent suggestion, but I'd avoid writing your name in bold, because the reader will assume that your name appears somewhere in the list of authors, there's no need to highlight that fact.

Comment: The preprint repository is interesting and would probably work in most cases, but I actually don't think the team *wants* it to be public, at least not for awhile (if ever, like I said, the point of this project is actually to build a database, not write a report). And I'm the most junior person on a 4-person team so I don't think I would want to be the one to broach that anyway. Thank you, though!